# Trying to understand macros that define file types

Tags: c, macros, gdb

So i've been trying to debug a program in gdb and for me to understand a certain part I needed to analyze it.

```
if (!S_ISREG(st->st_mode))

if (!(st->st_mode & S_IXUSR))
```

In the if's above, the S_ISREG and S_IXUSR are the macros that I don't understand. As I tried to investigate more into these macros I found these other macros:

```
/* File types.  */
#define __S_IFDIR       0040000 /* Directory.  */
#define __S_IFCHR       0020000 /* Character device.  */
#define __S_IFBLK       0060000 /* Block device.  */
#define __S_IFREG       0100000 /* Regular file.  */
#define __S_IFIFO       0010000 /* FIFO.  */
#define __S_IFLNK       0120000 /* Symbolic link.  */`enter code here`
#define __S_IFSOCK      0140000 /* Socket.  */
```

All i want to know is what the numbers next to the macros mean? And what about these macros starting with "__" I think I heard a while back that these were child macros or something. If someone can explain both of these it would be awesome!

Comment: It's impossible to know what a macro does unless you see its definition. Maybe show us a definition that we could translate?

Comment: As for the file type macros, those are just numbers (in octal) to distinguish different types of files on a system. The numbers probably don't mean anything by themselves but are just unique identifiers for each file type. The could be anything as long as they're distinct.

Comment: I want to know about the numbers, I know they mean something, its not about the definition of these macros.

Comment: They don't mean anything. They're just numbers. There was no specific reason to choose `0100000` for a regular file or `0040000` for a directory. They just needed a way to represent file types in C, and someone chose those numbers. It didn't matter what they were, as long as they were different from each other.

Answer (score 0):

You see, whoever created this file system just need some different value to represent different type of file,and one value to one type,there is not specific reason why 0040000 represents directory, if you are the author of the file system,you can specify any value you like to represent directory,so there is no why , just follow the comment and know it.